# Query table from Session value

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am using `$_SESSION[''];` to get values from a user after they have logged in. This data is coming from the `users` table.

I am then trying to `SELECT *` `FROM roster` table by doing a query and assigning a var for each value when the users API=$API

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include ('database_connection.php');

        $DOCSIGNEDBYIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $API = $_SESSION['API'];
        $FirstName = $_SESSION['firstname'];
        $LastName = $_SESSION['lastname'];
        $Email = $_SESSION['email'];
        $ExecutionDate = date();

     $query = "SELECT * FROM roster WHERE API='$API'";
          $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);  
          $address = $result['address'];
```

database_connection.php

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD,
 DATABASE_NAME);
```

I am not getting anything. No errors.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I am not getting any values, and not getting any errors.

Comment: From the looks of it, you're just making a query to your table. You have to use a function like `mysqli_num_rows` or `mysqli_fetch_array` in order to return the values that you want. Reference: [mysqli_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) or the link above for mysqli_num_rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `mysqli_fetch_array()` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` or similar function to return values from your `mysqli_query()` query. See below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM roster WHERE API='$API'";
$result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dbc, $query));
$address = $result['address'];
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: address in /home/.../public_html/url.org/home/page.php on line 19`

Comment: That means that `address` is not a column on the `roster` table. Double check your table structure and your query.

Comment: Doh! hehe I knew that. My 2 year old is loosing her crap and distracting me sorry. :)